# Function that computes projection and recostruction error using numpy - python

Tags: python, numpy, projection

I want to create a function that calculates and returns the projection of a vector x on a vector b as well as the reconstruction error.

My code is the following:

```
def reconstruction_error(x, b):

    '''The function calculates the projection and reconstruction error
    from projecting a vector x onto a vector b'''


    b = np.matrix(b)

    x_projection_on_b = (b.T @ b/ float((b@b.T))) @ x

    reconstruction_error = (x - x_projection_on_b) @ (x - x_projection_on_b).T 

    return( x_projection_on_b, float(reconstruction_error))
```

However the reconstruction error is not correct.  E.g.,

```
x = np.array([1,1,1])

b = np.array([5, 10, 10])

a, error = reconstruction_error(x, b)

a
matrix([[0.55555556, 1.11111111, 1.11111111]])

error
0.2222222222222222
```

Comment: What is the source of reconstruction error? Rounding?

Comment: what were you expecting?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about [terminology](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/194278/meaning-of-reconstruction-error-in-pca-and-lda), but if "reconstruction error" is length of "rejection vector" (original vector minus its projection), then you would have:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import norm

a = np.array([1,1,1])
b = np.array([5, 10, 10])    

def projection(x, on):
    return np.dot(x, on) / np.dot(on, on) * on

def rejection(x, on):
    return x - projection(x, on)

def reconstruction_error(x, on):
    return norm(rejection(x, on))

>>> reconstruction_error(a, b)
0.4714045207910317
```

Answer (score 0):

you are correct in your approach

reconstruction_error = (x - x_projection_on_b) @ (x - x_projection_on_b).T

However, what you have calculated above is squared norm.

Apply -> np.sqrt(reconstruction_error) to get the right answer